# SL API: vGPU image and instance creation from vGPU image

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to determine an image is vGPU capable? which means this image is created from a vGPU instance?

When creating instance from a vGPU image, what are flavor options available? is there an API to get the available flavor options? I captured an image template from a vGPU instance with flavor "AC1_8x60x25", when I am creating an instance from that image, I am given 2 flavor options "AC1_8x60x25" and "AC1_16x60x25". how to get the available flavor options from an vGPU image?

Thank you in advance!

Q. Z.

Answer (score 0):

•   Any image can be capable for GPU, your order just has to be in ¨Dallas13¨ datacenter and the disk you are going to select has to be the same size and type of the image.

•   The portal control filters only the presets that have the same size and type of disk as their image.

•   To get the available flavor option e.g. "AC¨ with 25 GB disk the same that the image has, you can use this rest api.

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getActivePresets?objectFilter={"activePresets":{"keyName":{"operation":"^=AC"},"prices":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"25 GB (SAN)"}}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the package id 835, keyName like "AC" from image by imageId? I am only able to get disk size by using API: https://[username]:[apiKey]api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/imageid.

Comment: To get the available package to create a virtual server from an image you can use the following rest api:
Method: POST
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/835/getAvailablePackagesForImageTemplate?objectMask=mask[activePresets]
Body: Json
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "id": 111111
      }
   ]
}   The id: 111111 is the imageId.

Comment: The control portal uses the package = 835 to create a virtual server with flavor. You can search in the response of this request the package 835 and you will see its presets or flavors available for the image. You can search the GPU options with the values AC or ACL.

Comment: I see, so package = 835 has all the available flavors for GPU. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, I noticed I am only given "San" type disk from an image which is generated from a GPU instance, while I can select "Local" or "San" disk type if the image is from an instance I manually select cpu, memory, disk etc. I am trying to check image's localDiskFlag by https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/[imageId]?objectMask=mask[flexImageFlag,children[transaction,blockDevices[diskImage[softwareReferences.softwareDescription,localDiskFlag]]]]

but no matter the disk is local or san, the flag returns false.

Comment: I researched about it, due to new features on VSI devices (dedicated instances, flavors, transit VSI), the localDiskFlag will be always false, it means will be able to order VSI it does not matter the type disk, the availability depends on prices for the VSI you want.

Comment: For GPU the flavor witch start with AC the disk will be SAN, and for ACL the disk is LOCAL. If you order through createObject method you do not need to set the attribute localDiskFlag when using flavors.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, what is the JSON payload to submit an instance creation from an image with GPU flavor by  using the method createObject of the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest service?

Comment: This is JSON payload that you can use:  { "parameters": [{
            "hostname": "test",
            "domain": "test.local",
            "datacenter": {
                "name": "dal13"
                },
            "hourlyBillingFlag": "true",
            "localDiskFlag": false,
            "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
                         "flavorKeyName": "AC1_8X60X25"
           },
           "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": 
                {  
                 "globalIdentifier": "4d1fa7dd-c7c2-42dc-9750-ef5c769d0770" 
                }
        }
    ]
}